How to ignore backface-culled faces that point away from the camera when selecting in edit mode?
I've been searching for days now, asking the reddit, discord, several streamers noone seems to know.
I'm looking for a way to ignore backface-culled faces that point away from the camera, so basically selecting faces inside of a mesh from the outside.
I got this cube that has its normals pointing inwards, imagine this is a room in a retro video game like ocarina of time or something:

When I now want to select faces inside the cube, from the outside, I can't:

This is a demonstration what I want to do specifically (I removed the sides of the cube which faces I was unintentionally selecting in the previous image):

The purpose of this is to more easily select faces for applying materials or other manipulation of retro-video game interiors, which usually don't have thickness to their walls and are just inside-normal-facing boxes.
